# Cannot submit app to the Windows store after adding cordova-plugin-ms-adal

Tags: adal

I added Azure AD authentication to my app using cordova-plugin-ms-adal. It works well, but when submitting the package to the Windows Store, I receive the following error

> You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages.

Also, when building it, I receive the following:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(934,5):
>   warning : Your application is missing a Runtim e Directives (rd.xml)
>   file. Runtime Directives are used to describe the dynamic behavior of
>   your application and control the .NET Native optimizer. It is
>   recommended to have at least one rd.xml file in your project.
>   [C:\dev\projects\first\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Wi ndows10.jsproj]

I receive none of them when I remove the plugin.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and building for Windows 10 with cordova 6.4 and cordova-windows 4.4.3.
Might be worth to mention, I am building the packages using this flag --archs="x86 x64 arm" because I am also using a sqlite plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more research on the error and some help, the issue is actually caused by trying to upload the appxbundle instead of the appxupload. 
And the reason why I was trying to upload the appxbundle is that there were no appxupload file generated.

The fact that no appxupload is generated is an issue when building for UAP in cordova-windows@4.4.3.
To generate the appxupload, I had to modify the build.js to add the StoreUpload option.

```
if (shouldBundle && index === configsArray.length - 1) {
    otherProperties.CordovaBundlePlatforms = bundleTerms;
    otherProperties.UapAppxPackageBuildMode = "StoreUpload";
} else if (shouldBundle) {
    otherProperties.CordovaBundlePlatforms = build.arch;
}
```

Hope that helps!